# Find specific combination of values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am preparing a dataframe for machine learning. The data set contains weather data from several weather stations in australia over a period of 10 years. One of the measured attributes is Evaporation. It has about 50% missing values.
Now I want to find out, whether the missing values are evenly distributed over all weather stations or if roughly half of the weather stations just never measured Evaporation.

How can I find out about the distribution of a value in combination with another attribute?
I basically want to loop over the weather stations and get a count of NaNs and normal values.

```
rain_df.query('Location == "Albury"').Location.count()
```

This gives me the number of measurement points from the weaher station in Albury. Now how can I find out how many NaNs were measured in Albury compared to normal (non-NaN) measurements?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas groupby count non-null values as percentage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47170311/pandas-groupby-count-non-null-values-as-percentage)

Comment: Yes this helps a lot thank you! 
Do you know how i can drop those instances, where there is only NaNs in a specific location? E.g. Albury has only NaNs in Evaporation, how can i now drop all instances from Albury?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.isnull()` to mask a series with True for NaNs and False for everything else. Then you can use `.value_counts(normalize=True)` to get the proportions of NaN and non NaN in that series.

```
rain_df.query('Location == "Albury"').Location.isnull().value_counts(normalize=True)
```